# Three JS BufferGeometry with simple image texture

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to apply simple image texture to bufferGeometry created using new ObjectLoader? Earlier we use to create MeshBasicMaterial with map to apply texture to any Geometry, but that doesnt seems to be working directly with bufferGeometry. Can someone provide an example to apply any image texture on any BufferGeometry? Or any kind of Util library that will make life easy with bufferGeometry textures?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the relevant part of your code so it is clear where you are having trouble.

Comment: @WestLangley I have uploaded my code on github. [GitHub](https://github.com/sushant380/ikea-v4) Please take a look at index.html for relevant code. The model file is bit heavy so it may take some time to load. in function buildMaterials, I am trying to apply floor texture using THREE.MeshPhongMaterial map, But it is just getting gray out.

Comment: Your model does not appear to have UVs specified.

Comment: Yeah, got the issue. Generated uvs with blender and now texture is appearing. Anyway to auto generate uvs using threejs?

Comment: Not for imported models -- only for certain built-in geometries.